# Passing hl.method does not change the Highlighter

Tags: solr, lucene

This happens on SOLR 5.5.1

When passing the hl.method parameter with the SOLR query the highlighter does not change.

If I explicitly set the highlighter component to the following:

```
    <searchComponent class="solr.HighlightComponent" name="highlight">
    <highlighting class="org.apache.solr.highlight.PostingsSolrHighlighter"/>
</searchComponent>
```

It does use the Postings Highlighter. My use case, however, requires me to use the DefaultHighlighter in one situation and the PostingsSolrHighligther in the other.

According to the documentation this should be possible by using the hl.method parameter.

What am I missing?

Comment: which value for hl.method you're using?

Comment: hl.method=postings, hl.method=unified and hl.method=original

Comment: all together? sorry, i didn't get it

Comment: nope, I have tried each option separately and none of them changed the behavior. It either stayed on the default highlighter or, when I set it fixed on in the solrconfig, the alternative highlighter.

Answer (score 1):

hl.method has been introduced in Solr 6.4, together with UnifiedHighlighter. I am assuming you are following the online Reference guide that is *live* and reflects the *next* version of Solr.

Usually that's ok, but sometimes it is worth consulting the guide specifically for your version. They are all still [available for the download](http://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/ref-guide/) in the PDF form.

Comment: well...that could explain it then :/ there are most likely no alternatives in dynamically choosing the highlighter in 5.5?